# Testing Django user and group permissions with a simple test fails

Tags: django, django-guardian

I've a model called Reminder that should be secured by django-guardian. Therefore I've created a very simple test that

- creates a user
- creates a Reminder instance
- assign permissions to the created reminder instance to the created user
- check those permissions again

```
class ReminderPermissionsTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):

        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Reminder)

        add_perm = Permission.objects.create(
            codename="add_reminder",
            name="Can add reminder",
            content_type=content_type
        )
        view_perm = Permission.objects.create(
            codename="view_reminder",
            name="Can view reminder",
            content_type=content_type
        )
        change_perm = Permission.objects.create(
            codename="change_reminder",
            name="Can change reminder",
            content_type=content_type
        )
        delete_perm = Permission.objects.create(
            codename="delete_reminder",
            name="Can delete reminder",
            content_type=content_type
        )

        editor_user = get_user_model().objects.create(username="user_user")

        reminder_crud = Reminder.objects.create(
            open=True,
            reminder_date="2023-09-03 12:00:00",
            subject="Reminder with CRUD permissions",
            created_by=editor_user,
            reminder_text="This is a reminder with CRUD permissions."
        )

    def test_editor_has_crud_permissions(self):
        editor_user = get_user_model().objects.get(username="editor_user")
        reminder_crud = Reminder.objects.get(subject="Reminder with CRUD permissions")

        assign_perm("change_reminder", editor_user, reminder_crud)
        assign_perm("delete_reminder", editor_user, reminder_crud)
        
        self.assertTrue(editor_user.has_perm("change_reminder", reminder_crud))
        self.assertTrue(editor_user.has_perm("delete_reminder", reminder_crud))
```

unfotuantely the test fails with

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 637, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
__fake__.Permission.DoesNotExist: Permission matching query does not exist
```

Full trace here: https://hastebin.com/share/afesunalel.scss

As you can see I've already explicitly created the permissions standard objects.
Unfortunately nothing helps. The permissions table stays empty

```
SELECT * FROM public.auth_permission
ORDER BY id ASC
```

that might explain the error.

Thankful for any hint how to solve this.

Comment: You don't need to call migrate manually if you use `from django.test import TestCase`.

Comment: With that said, what are you trying to test? What is the exact behavior you want to verify here? Describe it explictly in words and then we can talk about how to implement it. Also, please [edit] your question to include the entire error message.

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to test the `assign_perm()` function that you wrote. If that is the case, then you should call this function inside your `test_editor_has_crud_permissions()` function instead of `setUp()`. That way it only happens when you are testing it. In fact, I suggest having separate tests: `test_user_has_change_permissions()` and `test_editor_has_delete_permissions()`. Or really, you can have a single test `test_user_has_permission()` to verify that whatever the given permission, it is correctly assigned to the user.

Comment: I think you shouldn't call `Permission.objects.create()` at all. If you set up your test correctly, the django test runner will run migrations for you when you first run your test suite. These migrations will then create all the necessary permissions objects for your system.

Comment: Thanks I've updated my question so hopefully it gets more clear. This is really a simple test as a start to test permissions on an object. I've shared the full stacktrace via hastebin as otherwise the code gets to long and SO prevents saving

Comment: @Code-Apprentice without `Permission.objects.create()` I do get the same reslut. Thats why I've tried to explicitly create the Permissions!

Comment: (as written in my question)

Answer (score 1):

I could solve my problem by raising the verbosity level

python manage.py test --verbosity 2 reminders

this showed that it is not my test code that fails but a migration when creating the test database